# How do I search files in Eclipse so the results shows files that do NOT contain the search term?

Tags: eclipse, search

In Eclipse editor, if I go Search->File, I can search for files that contain my search term. What I want to do is find all of the files that **DO NOT** contain my search term. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking "regular expression" option and then input somethign like [^term] or (?!term) -- meaning of both of this is 'not term' but they are slightly different (please refer to some RegExp documentation like [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

Comment: Hi. I tried these. The [^term] works but doesn't give the results I want. The other style, while not giving an error as a malformed regexp or anything, gives no results. I am trying to work through the info on the link you provided to see if I can work this out. Thanks

Comment: `[^term]` defines a character group (`[]`) without the characters `t`, `e`, `r` and `m`. So you don’t exclude the word `term` but the letters `t`, `e`, `r` and `m`.

Comment: "Try-this" answer with a wrong suggestion and no example at all: this answer must be deleted.

Answer (score 46):

This expression should work ([reference](http://eclipsemde.blogspot.com/2009/02/negative-search.html)):

```
(?s)\A((?!YourSearchText).)*\Z
```

Comment: This should really be marked as the answer. Thanks!

Can anyone explain this regex to me? I understand the ?! group, but wouldn't \A and \Z be matching the literal characters?

Comment: @JacobEnsor (?s) enables single-line mode making the dot "." match line breaks too.  \A and \Z match the beginning and end of input. (?!YourSearchText) means "YourSearchText is not present at this point". So it basically matches all input characters as long as YourSearchText is not found. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Also, `(?s)\A(?!.*YourSearchText)` can work. Its performance is not great, but it will do the job, optimization depends on the text to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way imo is to use [InstaSearch Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) and type:

`search text -wordToExclude -anotherWordToExclude`