# Eclipse find all java classes that have no tests in them

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project with many classes. It's easy to find all the classes that have methods with  @Test annotation.

What I want to achieve is find all the classes that DON'T have methods with this annotation(or simply the class doesn't have that string contained).

Is this doable via Eclipse ?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149057/how-do-i-search-files-in-eclipse-so-the-results-shows-files-that-do-not-contain

Comment: @halex But OP has to search only classes that are actually TestCases and not in all classes. Will the above link help in that case?

Comment: @halex indeed voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Search with (?!.*(\@Test)).* as regular expression in the file search on *.java. 
It will count every match, so you won't get the number of files. But the file search result will show all files neatly.

The positive search would be (.*(\@Test)).* (just to check it).