# How to search for files that not containing some text?

Tags: eclipse, search

In Eclipse when you press Ctrl + H it opens a window to search a text in files. no i want to find the files that does not contain some text. can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Do the same thing i.e. pres CTR+H and select File Search, enter  ^((?!YourText).)*$  in search field and select Regular Expression."Your text" in regular expression is the string which should not contained in file.Do the search and find expected files.

Comment: It doesn't work, please test your regular expression in http://regexr.com.

Comment: this works (?s)\A((?!YourText).)*\Z, reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149057/how-do-i-search-files-in-eclipse-so-the-results-shows-files-that-do-not-contain#answer-7180566